# How to create windows xp bootable usb from lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, windows

I am using Lubuntu 18.04.4LTS and i need to create windows xp installation device or usb, i tried to do that with `dd` and "WoeUSB" and because of 32bit system i can not install unetbootin.
when i tried with `dd` there is no response from usb after selecting usb to boot from and when i tried with WoeUSB there is a terminal only which have no particular instructions to use or i do not  know how to use that, is there any other way to create stable installation medium for windows xp from lubuntu 18.04.4LTS?

Answer (score 2):

Open the Lubuntu menu and find the `startup disk creator` and click on it.

When the window opens, select your Windows XP ISO disk image in the `source disk image`field and the removable drive in the `disk to use field`.

[image: make startup disk]

The click the `make startup disk` button and wait for the process to complete!

For more information, see [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview) from Ubuntu Documentation.

Comment: Thank you for response, this is not working and i think this is for only Ubuntu, no other os, i clicked on windows xp iso and nothing, then i tried to select fedora iso and that is not showing in window above too.

Comment: I confirm that this is not just for Ubuntu. Did you select other and then select the Win XP ISO? You can also try some alternative ways from this article (ignore the first 2 ways): https://fossbytes.com/create-bootable-usb-media-from-iso-ubuntu/

Comment: yes i did, and with other linux distributions too. but no, that is not picking them up.\

Comment: Try with using ddrescue. See the third way in this article: https://fossbytes.com/create-bootable-usb-media-from-iso-ubuntu/

Comment: The Windows XP ISO image is probably not a "hybrid ISO" file so simply writing it a USB drive won't make it bootable. See https://superuser.com/questions/683210/how-do-i-determine-if-an-iso-is-a-hybrid for more information.